# jQuery DOM manipulation won't get the href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using this code, I am trying to get the `href` attribute of a link and make a new link of that attribute. Why my link does not work, I don't know. It shows something like this:

> 404 - The page cannot be found
>
> [Sorry, we cannot find the page](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/text).
>
> It might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.
>
> Please check that the Web site address is spelled correctly.
>
> Or go to our home page, and use the menus to navigate to a specific
>   section.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      text ="";
      text +=$("#w3s").attr("href");

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<a href=\'text\'>W3Schools.com</a>";
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" id="w3s">W3Schools.com</a></p>

<button>Show href Value</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

If I use:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

It shows `http://www.w3schools.com`. Why doesn't the link go to this site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to use jQuery to traverse and manipulate the DOM, use jQuery. If you're going to use vanilla javascript... do that. Just try not mix them! Makes things easier in the long run. Anyway, you could do something like this to set the href attribute;

```
$('#demo').attr('href', text);
```

or

```
document.getElementById('demo').href = text;
```

btw this

```
"<a href=\'text\'>W3Schools.com</a>"
```

Is totally not how you do string concatenation in javascript. Should be

```
'<a href="' + text + '">W3Schools.com</a>'
```

Comment: You forgot quotes around literal of href `...href='" + text + "'>W3Schools...`

Comment: yahhh that was soo fool

Comment: "btw" means "by the way". Doesn't it? If so, you've made it sound as if the problem with writing `"<a href=\'text\'>W3Schools.com</a>"` is just a side issue, when in fact it's the whole reason why the code doesn't work. It's the other stuff that should be under "btw".